# Personal VBA enabled Workbook won't open with excel

Tags: vba, excel

My personal vba enabled workbook came into existence when I recorded and then tweaked vba code. However if I close Excel and open it back up the vba enabled workbook is gone. I can't see it in the editor. I can find it(C:\Users\User ID\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART) and open it manually but is there a way to make it stick around?

Comment: It should be listed under the VBE or do you mean the workbook?

Comment: It isn't in the VBE until i go to C:\Users\User ID\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART and open it manually or record a new macro in personal macro workbook but then I lose my other macros.

Comment: Huh. Might have been corrupted. May be easier to start from scratch rather than troubleshoot it? Save the code elsewhere then delete the current one and create a new one.

Comment: The personal Macro workbook is hidden by default. Try View > Unhide

Comment: Check under *File>>Excel Options>>Addins>>Manage... - Disabled Items*  Sometimes a workbook will get listed there if it has code which is causing a problem for Excel.

Comment: Luuklag seems to have edited my question. It is no longer asking what I intended. The "Personal Macro Workbook" (not a vba enabled workbook) was acting up but Tim Williams and Don Jewetts comments helped me resolve the issue.